# Удаление повторяющихся предложений из текстового документа

Tags: java

я начинаю только изучать Java. У меня есть готовый код, с написанными тестами. Логи по тестам заносятся в документ .txt, иногда эти логи дублируются, мне необходимо удалить из документа все задублированные логи. Подскажите, как это реализовать

Это код по которому логи заносятся в текстовый файл

```
введите сюда public class FileTestLogger extends TestLogger {
int step = 1;
String folderName = "";

public void deleteFiles(String folderName){
    File listFile = new File("src/test/java/logFiles/" + folderName);
    File exportFiles[] = listFile.listFiles();

    if (listFile.listFiles() == null) {
        listFile.mkdir();
    }

    if (listFile.listFiles().length != 0) {
       /* for (int i = 0; i <= listFile.listFiles().length; i++) {
            delete(exportFiles[i]); //delete all old log files
        }
        */
       deleteDir(listFile);
       listFile.mkdir();
    }
}

void deleteDir(File file) {
    File[] contents = file.listFiles();
    if (contents != null) {
        for (File f : contents) {
            deleteDir(f);
        }
    }
    file.delete();
}

@Override
public void log(String folderName, String fileName, String msg) {
    try {

        //String fullFolderName = folderName + new Date();

        File listFile = new File("src/test/java/logFiles/" + folderName);
        File exportFiles[] = listFile.listFiles();

        if (listFile.listFiles() == null) {
            listFile.mkdir();
        }

        if (step == 1) {
            if (listFile.listFiles().length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= listFile.listFiles().length; i++) {
                    delete(exportFiles[i]); //delete all old log files
                }
            }



        }



        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/test/java/logFiles/" + folderName + "/" + fileName, true);



        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());

        if (step == 1) {
            w.write("Test Case: \n");
            w.append('\n');
        }
        w.write(time + " " + msg);
        step++;
        w.append('\n');
        w.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void log(String msg) {

}

public void delete(File file) {
    if (!file.exists())
        return;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File f : file.listFiles())
            delete(f);
        file.delete();
    } else {
        file.delete();
    }
}код
```

и вот пример записи логов в файл

> Test Case: Test Case: 22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 2 (text). URL:/report 22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 3 (digits). URL:/report 22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 2 (text). URL: /report

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример того лога. Мб вам нужно не удалять дубликаты из файла, а не заносить их?

Comment: и вот пример записи логов в файл est Case: 
Test Case: 

22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 2 (text). URL:/report
22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 3 (digits). URL:/report
22.01.19 11:04 Test Case 2 (text). URL: /report

Comment: Мне нужно если ссылка полностью совпадает- не дублировать ее. в моем случае, это "URL:/report"

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким способом проверять есть ли искомая строка в файле:

```
public static boolean findLogText(String textOfYourLog, String fileName) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    String content = IOUtils.toString(fis);
    fis.close();
    return content.contains(textOfYourLog);

}
```